# How to exit with non zero code using Python Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, exit-code

I have a use case where I want my script that runs multiple functions parallelly using multiprocessing to exit with non zero code  and that should stop running the script immediately on seeing the return code 1 or errors from any of the functions.

Here is what I am trying to do, not sure if my approach is correct and what should I do further.

```
def a(a1):
  if a1==a2:
    print("success")
    return 0
 else:
    print("failure")
    return 1 #or sys.exit(1) - not sure which 1 should I use here

def b(b1):
  if b1==b2:
    print("success")
    return 0
 else:
    print("failure")
    return 1  #or sys.exit(1) - not sure which 1 should I use here

def runall():
  if __name__ =='__main__':
    t1= multiprocess.Process(target=a, args=a1)
    t1= multiprocess.Process(target=b, args=b1)
    
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

Comment: why is `if __name__ =='__main__':` inside the `runall` function? see https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html for more conventional usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exit completely you can just use `sys.exit()` without argument. Just the documentation says:

> The sys.exit() function allows the developer to exit from Python. The
> exit function takes an optional argument, typically an integer, that
> gives an exit status. Zero is considered a “successful termination”.
> Be sure to check if your operating system has any special meanings for
> its exit statuses so that you can follow them in your own application.
> Note that when you call exit, it will raise the SystemExit exception,
> which allows cleanup functions to work in the finally clauses of try /
> except blocks.

If you want to know which function terminated the program you can use different integer.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer on my question. I am expecting my program to exit by returning  some non zero exit code and since am using multiprocessing so If any of the function doesn't get completed due to any other error, multiprocess should return the non exit code on that too instead of looking for other functions to run.

Comment: Ok, so you can use different int value inside the sys.exit() from different funcionts

Comment: @user12252991 if the answer is useful upvote and mark as accepted

Comment: I think my runall() method is not even correct, I want my code correction Please so that it works as I am expecting it work, something like which is done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171702/python-multiprocessing-exit-condition-error-intermittently

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `multiprocessing.Process` instances, I would use a multiprocessing pool (of size 2) because it is easier to get a return value back from your "worker functions", `a` and `b`. Then I would submit the two "tasks" using the `apply_async` method specifying a *callback* function that will be invoked when each task completes and will be passed the return value from that task. If any task completes with a result of 1, method `terminate` will be called against the pool, which will immediately kill all pool processes.

In the demo below I have arranged for `b` to fail and have introduced a delay in `a` so that `b` fails before `a` can complete demonstrating that `a` never completes because of the call to `terminate`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

a1 = 1
b2 = 1

def a(a1):
    import time

    time.sleep(1)
    if a1 == a2:
        print("a success")
        return 0
    else:
        print("a failure")
        return 1

def b(b1):
    if b1 == b2:
        print("b success")
        return 0
    else:
        print("b failure")
        return 1

def check_result(result):
    if result == 1:
        # kill all pool processes:
        pool.terminate()

def runall():
    global pool

    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.apply_async(a, args=(1,), callback=check_result)
    # This task will fail:
    pool.apply_async(b, args=(2,), callback=check_result)
    # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete or for
    # the pool to be terminated:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runall()
```

Prints:

```None
b failure
```